# Is interleaving ON_CALL and calls to mock functions also undefined?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

It's very clear from [the docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/e8512bc38c4c0060858c3306b0660a3f126aee30/docs/gmock_for_dummies.md) that interleaving `EXPECT_CALL()` and calls to the mock function is undefined behavior in gmock, and it gets reiterated quite a bit (see e.g. [Interleaving EXPECT_CALL()s and calls to the mock functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089204/interleaving-expect-calls-and-calls-to-the-mock-functions/40104286#40104286)).

[The documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/e8512bc38c4c0060858c3306b0660a3f126aee30/docs/gmock_for_dummies.md), however, specifically calls out `EXPECT_CALL()`:

> Important note: gMock requires expectations to be set before the mock functions are called, otherwise the behavior is undefined. In particular, you mustn't interleave `EXPECT_CALL()`s and calls to the mock functions.

**Does this warning also apply to using `ON_CALL()`?**

The general problem I face is that we're very frequently passing mock objects to the constructor of a uut in a test fixture, and sometimes the constructors actually need to use those mocks to initialize the uut to a specific state, so that we can then write a bunch of tests which verify the behavior when the object is in that state.

To illustrate the situation:

```
class MyFixture : public testing::Test {
 public:
  NiceMock<MyMock> mock;
  std::unique_ptr<MyUut> uut;
  MyFixture() {
    ON_CALL(mock, Something()).WillByDefault(Return(MyMock::SOME_VALUE));

    // constructor uses mock->Something() to initialize.
    uut = std::make_unique<MyUut>(&mock);

    // are we in UB-land?
  }
};

TEST_F(MyFixture, InvokesFooWhenDoingSomething) {
   EXPECT_CALL(mock, Foo());
   uut->DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Isn't calling a virtual function in constructors isn't a bad practice?

Comment: @Luca Many people consider calling a class's *own* virtual functions during construction bad practice. I've never heard of calling the virtual functions of *other* objects being an issue.